# How do I configure my Django serializer to return validation errors in its errors array as opposed to throwing an exception?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using Django 3.0 with Python 3.7 and the Django rest framework.  I want to test one of my serializers (code below) so I wrote this test.  Notice I intentionally wanted some of the fields to be invalid to test the error messages ...

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_coop_create_with_incomplete_data(self):
    """ Test coop serizlizer model """
    phone = "7731112222"
    serializer_data = {
        "name": "",
        "types": [
        ],
        "addresses": [{
            "formatted": "",
            "locality": {
                "name": "",
                "postal_code": "",
                "state": ""
            }
        }],
        "enabled": "true",
        "phone": {
          "phone": phone
        },
        "email": {
          "email": ""
        },
        "web_site": ""
    }

    serializer = CoopSerializer(data=serializer_data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False)
    print(serializer.errors)
    print("=================\n\n\n")
```

but instead of returning the errors in the ".errors()" function, "is_valid" is throwing an exception, below,

```
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/tests/test_serializers.py", line 132, in test_coop_create_with_incomplete_data
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 234, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 433, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 490, in to_internal_value
    validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 565, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 519, in to_internal_value
    return [
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 520, in <listcomp>
    self.child_relation.to_internal_value(item)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/web/directory/serializers.py", line 31, in to_internal_value
    locality, created = Locality.objects.get_or_create(**locality)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 562, in get_or_create
    return self._create_object_from_params(kwargs, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 604, in _create_object_from_params
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 596, in _create_object_from_params
    obj = self.create(**params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 433, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 886, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 923, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1377, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'state_id' cannot be null")
```

How do I configure the serializer to return the exceptions so I can check them as opposed to throwing the exceptions and stopping execution?  Evidently "raise_exception=False" is not doing the trick.

Below is my model, which references the DJango address package -- https://github.com/furious-luke/django-address

```
class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_phone')
    email = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_email')
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

and here are the relevant serializers ...

```
class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    types = CoopTypeSerializer(many=True)
    addresses = AddressTypeField(many=True)
    phone = ContactMethodPhoneSerializer()
    email = ContactMethodEmailSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Coop
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'types', 'addresses', 'phone', 'enabled', 'email', 'web_site']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['types'] = CoopTypeSerializer(instance.types.all(), many=True).data
        rep['addresses'] = AddressSerializer(instance.addresses.all(), many=True).data
        return rep

    def create(self, validated_data):
        #"""
        #Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        #"""

        coop_types = validated_data.pop('types', {})
        phone = validated_data.pop('phone', {})
        email = validated_data.pop('email', {})
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        for item in coop_types:
            coop_type, _ = CoopType.objects.get_or_create(name=item['name']) 
            instance.types.add(coop_type)
        print("phone:",phone)
        instance.phone = ContactMethod.objects.create(type=ContactMethod.ContactTypes.PHONE, **phone)
        instance.email = ContactMethod.objects.create(type=ContactMethod.ContactTypes.EMAIL, **email)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Coop` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        try:
            coop_types = validated_data['types']
            instance.types.clear()  # Disassociates all  CoopTypes from instance.
            for item in coop_types:
                coop_type, _ = CoopType.objects.get_or_create(**item)
                instance.types.add(coop_type)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        instance.addresses = validated_data.get('addresses', instance.addresses)
        instance.enabled = validated_data.get('enabled', instance.enabled)
        instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone', instance.phone)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.web_site = validated_data.get('web_site', instance.web_site)
        instance.web_site = validated_data.get('web_site', instance.web_site)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    locality = LocalityTypeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['id', 'street_number', 'route', 'raw', 'formatted', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'locality']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['locality'] = LocalitySerializer(instance.locality).data
        return rep

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `AddressField` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        address = AddressTypeField.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return address

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `AddresssField` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.street_number = validated_data.get('street_number', instance.name)
        instance.route = validated_data.get('route', instance.name)
        instance.raw = validated_data.get('raw', instance.name)
        instance.formatted = validated_data.get('formatted', instance.name)
        instance.latitude = validated_data.get('latitude', instance.name)
        instance.longitude = validated_data.get('longitude', instance.name)
        instance.locality = validated_data.get('locality', instance.name)
        instance.save()
        return instance


class LocalitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Locality 
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'postal_code', 'state']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['state'] = StateSerializer(instance.state).data
        return rep

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Locality` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Locality.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Locality` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.postal_code = validated_data.get('postal_code', instance.name)
        instance.state = validated_data.get('state', instance.name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `if` `else` with your `serializer.is_valid()` and then print `serializer.errors()`.

Something like this:

```
serializer = CoopSerializer(data=serializer_data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    # DO SOMETHING HERE OR PRINT
    print("works")
else:
    print(serializer.errors)
    print("=================\n\n\n")
```